# Calculate the time after converting into a new datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

Goal:
To display data with this list:

```
Hour  
-----
2
2,5
1
```

Problem:
Is it any possibiltiy to convert column StartTime and EndTime into specific datatype and then doing  a calculacution of X1- X2

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(   
    StartTime VARCHAR(5), 
    EndTime VARCHAR(5), 
)   
GO

INSERT INTO Data(StartTime,EndTime)   
SELECT '10:00','12:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '13:30','16:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '14:00','15:00' UNION ALL
GO
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: What is the specific data type you are looking for? Why do you want to convert StartTime and EndTime? What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:** To get mins in decimals

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST( Mins AS FLOAT)/60,2) AS [hour]
FROM (
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(StartTime AS TIME),CAST(EndTime AS TIME)) AS Mins 
    FROM  Data
) A
```

Comment: It doesn't work in sql2005 because of TIME datatype, also has two selects where only one is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(DATETIME, StartTime), CONVERT(DATETIME, EndTime)) 
                    / 60.0 AS Hour
FROM Data
```

It work's for your example data, but you should check if EndTime could be the next day, like:

StarTime: 22:30

EndTime:  01:20

Is that escenario possible? If it is, you must store the date for both Start and End times, not only the hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL-SERVER 2008, then why not just use the [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) object. You could then run the appropriate time comparison functions. If not, you can still make it work by [converting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to a datetime and running comparison functions. I believe a convert with just a time to a datetime will result in the date as the minimum date.